# Yosys: Multiple edge sensitivities for asynchronous reset

Tags: verilog, signal-processing, fpga, yosys, ice40

I am teaching myself verilog, bare with me. :)

I have a clock line called `enable` coming from a clock divider I created.

I also have a `rst` button on my devboard.

I would like to modify the following code to react to `rst` button presses by turning off my leds:

```
always @ (posedge enable) begin
    if (leds == 8'b11111111) begin
        leds <= 8'b00000000;
    end else begin
        leds <= 8'b11111111;
    end
end
```

I added my `rst` button as an additional edge sensitivity and caught it in an `if` statement:

```
always @ (posedge enable or negedge rst) begin
    if (leds == 8'b11111111 || ~rst) begin
        leds <= 8'b00000000;
    end else begin
        leds <= 8'b11111111;
    end
end
```

When I synthesize this for `ice40` using `yosys`, I get the following error: `ERROR: Multiple edge sensitive events found for this signal`

If it helps, the previous line of `yosys` output suggests that this `always` block is translated to a dff cell during synthesis.

I have seen several examples of people including asynchronous resets in their always blocks, so I am curious if somebody can teach me what I am violating in my case, as a novice to verilog/digital-logic.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of synthesizers expect the code to follow certain coding styles. If your synthesizer supports async-reset then try making the reset logic exclusive.

```
always @ (posedge enable or negedge rst) begin
    if (~rst) begin
        leds <= 8'b00000000;
    end else if (leds == 8'b11111111) begin
        leds <= 8'b00000000;
    end else begin
        leds <= 8'b11111111;
    end
end
```

Your `leds == 8'b11111111 || ~rst` is logically equivalent. I haven't used a synthesizer smart enough to recognize it as logically equivalent.

Comment: Although I believe it's officially obsolete, IEEE 1364.1 is a good reference to what coding styles any synthesiser should be able to support.